# Realizar consulta con conjunto de datos como parámetros

Tags: sql, sql-server, transacciones, transact-sql

Estoy desarrollando un modulo de reporte para un sistema, dentro de un menu existen dropdowns que contienen multiples checkbox estos son parámetros(cuyo valor son primarykey's) de búsqueda estas al enviar el formulario las recibo almacenados en variables de tipo `string` separados por una `,`; en el backend recibo estos variables de tipo string y las envío al motor de base de datos, con esta consulta:

```
SELECT   S.IDScrap
        , S.fecha
        , M.modelo
        , E.estacion 
        , C.correccion
        , S.elemento
        , P.nombre
        , P.numeroparte
        , Sp.cantidad
FROM            dbo.Scrap           S 
INNER JOIN      dbo.Estacion        E   ON  E.IDEstacion    =   S.IDEstacion
INNER JOIN      dbo.Modelo          M   ON  S.IDModelo      =   M.IDModelo
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Scrapcorreccion Sc  ON  S.IDScrap       =   Sc.IDScrap
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Correccion      C   ON  C.IDCorrecion   =   Sc.IDCorrecion 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Scraparte       Sp  ON  S.IDScrap       =   Sp.IDScrap
LEFT JOIN       dbo.Parte           P   ON  Sp.IDParte      =   P.IDParte 
WHERE S.fecha   >= @fecha 
AND   S.fecha   <= DATEADD(HOUR,23.9999,@fechafin)
AND   S.IDModelo IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@ID_Model_list,','))
AND   S.IDEstacion IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@ID_Station_list,','))
AND    Sc.IDCorrecion IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@ID_Correc_list,','))
AND   Sp.IDParte IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@ID_Name_list,',')) 
OR    Sp.IDParte IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@ID_Part_list,','))
```

La intención es que pueda resultar un reporte dependiendo de los Checkboxes que eligió el usuario,la consulta de arriba arroja fechas que no corresponden a los parámetros u omite registros.
La variables que recibo vienen de esta forma, por ejemplo

```
@ID_Model_list = '1,2' 
@ID_Station_list = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39'
```

Tomo de ejemplo esta consulta y resultado, donde solo estoy filtrando por los campos de fechas, donde fechas los obtengo de un input de tipo date con el formato `'2022-07-11'`

```
SELECT   S.IDScrap
        , S.fecha
        , M.modelo
        , E.estacion 
        , C.correccion
        , S.elemento
        , P.nombre
        , P.numeroparte
        , Sp.cantidad
FROM            dbo.Scrap           S 
INNER JOIN      dbo.Estacion        E   ON  E.IDEstacion    =   S.IDEstacion
INNER JOIN      dbo.Modelo          M   ON  S.IDModelo      =   M.IDModelo
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Scrapcorreccion Sc  ON  S.IDScrap       =   Sc.IDScrap
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Correccion      C   ON  C.IDCorrecion   =   Sc.IDCorrecion 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Scraparte       Sp  ON  S.IDScrap       =   Sp.IDScrap
LEFT JOIN       dbo.Parte           P   ON  Sp.IDParte      =   P.IDParte 
WHERE S.fecha   >= '2022-07-11' 
AND   S.fecha   <= DATEADD(HOUR,23.9999,'2022-07-15')
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, cuando el usuario seleccione los modelos del checkbox `model` (por ejemplo) se envía la variable de tipo `string @ID_Model_list` con el valor `'1,2'` en la consulta debo evaluar S.IDModelo para que retorne las filas donde se cumple que `S.IDModelo = 1 AND S.IDModelo = 2`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si (por ejemplo) de los Checkboxes `Station` selecciono algunas opciones y formo la variable `@ID_Station_list` con los valores `1,3,7,9` debo poder evaluar la condición donde se cumplan los parámetros para `S.IDModelo = 1 AND S.IDModelo = 2` && `S.IDEstacion = 1 AND S.IDEstacion = 3 AND S.IDEstacion = 7 AND S.IDEstacion = 9`

Este comportamiento se debe de repetir para el resto de parámetros, `@ID_Model_list`, `@ID_Station_list`, `@ID_Correc_list`, `@ID_Name_list`,  `@ID_Part_list`

Intente evaluar con la función `IN`, con la función `CONTAINS`, pero no realiza las evaluaciones, actualmente transforme `@ID_Model_list` en una columna con la instrucción `SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@ID_Model_list,',')` pero solo evalúa el primer valor de la columna
S.IDModelo IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@ID_Model_list,',')

*¿Que debo de cambiar en la consulta para que pueda evaluar todos los valores contenidos en* `@ID_Model_list`, `@ID_Station_list`, `@ID_Correc_list`, `@ID_Name_list`,  `@ID_Part_list` *?*

Comment: "Cómo puedo mejorar la consulta" que queres mejorar?

Comment: La consulta no genera la información de forma correcta, los registros que arroja son incompletos y no cumples con los parámetros de la consulta

Comment: y cual es la informacion correcta? y cual es la informacion que muestra? y con cuales datos? y con cuales parametros? los registros estan incompletos porque.... que datos le faltan?? y no cumplen con los parametros.. que datos? que parametros? o sea.. a tu pregunta es como que le falta mucha informacion.. y son muchas preguntas en una.. no?

Comment: Hay cosas que mencionas pero es imposible entender sin estar dentro de tu mente. Es esencial que nos cuentes mejor dónde están los datos (estructura de las tablas), un par de registros de prueba y una salida esperada. Todo esto yendo a [edit] la pregunta. No sabemos cómo revisar si los join están bien (porque no conocemos las tablas); no sabemos de dónde salen esas variables @fecha para suponer que estás buscando bien o mal. No sabemos si la fecha está en un campo date o cómo está...

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias!, actualizare el post, para que sea un poco mas entendible mi problema, solo que no encuentro donde subir el diagrama para compartirlo, en una imagen no se apreciaría bien

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la condición toma toda la cadena como un solo valor. Para hacer funcional ese método es necesario dividir la cadena en distintos valores. Una de las mejores funciones disponibles, se puede encontrar [aquí junto con su explicación](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

También dejo el código de la función para crearla.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
 WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

Una vez teniendo esta función, se puede adaptar el código que tienes.

```
SELECT S.IDScrap
     , S.fecha
     , M.modelo
     , E.estacion 
     , C.correccion
     , S.elemento
     , P.nombre
     , P.numeroparte
     , Sp.cantidad
FROM            dbo.Scrap           S 
INNER JOIN      dbo.Estacion        E  ON E.IDEstacion  = S.IDEstacion 
INNER JOIN      dbo.Modelo          M  ON S.IDModelo    = M.IDModelo
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Scrapcorreccion Sc ON S.IDScrap     = Sc.IDScrap 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Correccion      C  ON C.IDCorrecion = Sc.IDCorrecion 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Scraparte       Sp ON S.IDScrap     = Sp.IDScrap 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Parte           P  ON Sp.IDParte    = P.IDParte 
WHERE S.fecha      >= @fecha 
AND S.fecha        <= DATEADD(HOUR,23.9999,@fechafin) 
AND S.IDModelo     IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@ID_Model_list  , ',')s) 
AND S.IDEstacion   IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@ID_Station_list, ',')s)
AND Sc.IDCorrecion IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@ID_Correc_list , ',')s)
AND Sp.IDParte     IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@ID_Part_list   , ',')s) 
OR Sp.IDParte      IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@ID_Part_list   , ',')s);
```

Comment: Gracias Luis, para eso estaba intentando con la función 'string_split' que me retorna como columnas los IDs que vienen en la cadena, pero aun así los resultados 
de las consultas están mal

Comment: Si tienes acceso a STRING_SPLIT, puede ser una mejor opción. Respecto a que los resultados están mal, te recomiendo revisar tus condiciones. La última condición puede invalidar el resto.